# How can you get to play with tanks in VS mode in Star Fox 64?

Tags: starfox-64

I heard earlier today that you can play as tanks in vs mode in Star Fox 64.... Is this possible?   If it is, how can I unlock this mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to earn a medal on planet Venom, where you fight Andross.

To earn that medal, you'll need to kill 200 enemies and keep your wing-men alive.